# Want to change complex Json structure which I need change it array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript and I am facing issue with complex structure with I need to break into array.

my structure is

```
   [
    {
        "Key": "ProducePRINKA0370001",
        "Record": {
            "docType": "Produce",
            "PRODUCEID": "PRINKA0370001"
        }
    },
    {
        "Key": "ProducePRINKA0370038",
        "Record": {
            "docType": "Produce",
            "PRODUCEID": "PRINKA0370038"
        }
    },
    {
        "Key": "ProducePRINKA0370050",
        "Record": {
            "docType": "Produce",
            "PRODUCEID": "PRINKA0370050"
          
        }
    }
]
```

Which I need to break into array and its should look below

```
 [
    {
        "docType": "Produce",
        "PRODUCEID": "PRINKA0370051"
    },
    
        {
        "docType": "Produce",
        "PRODUCEID": "PRINKA0370038"
    }
    
    
]
```

I have tried all the way however couldn't do it. Please help me on this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it easily using [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows -

```js
const myArr = [{
    "Key": "ProducePRINKA0370001",
    "Record": {
      "docType": "Produce",
      "PRODUCEID": "PRINKA0370001"
    }
  },
  {
    "Key": "ProducePRINKA0370038",
    "Record": {
      "docType": "Produce",
      "PRODUCEID": "PRINKA0370038"
    }
  },
  {
    "Key": "ProducePRINKA0370050",
    "Record": {
      "docType": "Produce",
      "PRODUCEID": "PRINKA0370050"

    }
  }
];

const modifiedArr = myArr.map((el) => {
  return el.Record;
})

console.log(modifiedArr)
```

The above code just maps over your initial array (`myArr` in this case) and just returns the `Record` part from each of the objects in the `myArr` array. Finally what `map()` built-in function of JS does is that it returns an array consisting of all elements which you return in the function provided inside `map`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use map function to get the result you want.

```
var result = source.map((item) => item["Record"]);

console.log(result);
```

Here `source` is the array of the source array.